# Difference between dislocation, shifting, inversion, discontinuity, topicalization, scrambling

Tags: syntax, terminology

This is a really broad question, but can someone explain the difference between the following phenomena: topicalization, dislocation, shifting, inversion, discontinuity, and scrambling. Wikipedia says scrambling doesn't occur in English, so translated examples from other languages would work.

I think I understand very well the phenomena on their own and their definitions and examples of them and so forth, but I want to understand the relationship among them and their categorization.

Comment: These are not all the same kind of thing, but most of them are syntactic rules. So [start here for examples in English](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf).